# React Hook Form resolver Moment

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, yup

I'm creating a form using React Hook Form V7 and utilizing @hookform/yupResolver. I'm getting this error:

```
Type '<TFieldValues extends FieldValues, TContext>(values: UnpackNestedValue<TFieldValues>, context: TContext | undefined, options: ResolverOptions<TFieldValues>) => Promise<...>' is not assignable to type 'Resolver<ReporterInformationModel, object>'.
  Types of parameters 'options' and 'options' are incompatible.
    Type 'ResolverOptions<ReporterInformationModel>' is not assignable to type 'ResolverOptions<{ city?: Nullable<string> | undefined; dateOfBirth?: { format: {}; startOf: {}; endOf: {}; add: {}; subtract: {}; calendar: {}; clone: {}; valueOf: {}; local: {}; isLocal
: {}; utc: {}; isUTC: {}; ... 76 more ...; propertyIsEnumerable: {}; } | null | undefined; ... 11 more ...; zip?: Nullable<...> | u...'.
      Type '{ format: {}; startOf: {}; endOf: {}; add: {}; subtract: {}; calendar: {}; clone: {}; valueOf: {}; local: {}; isLocal: {}; utc: {}; isUTC: {}; isUtc: {}; parseZone: {}; isValid: {}; invalidAt: {}; hasAlignedHourOffset: {}; ... 71 more ...; propertyIsEnum
erable: {}; } | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Datable | undefined'.
        Type '{ format: {}; startOf: {}; endOf: {}; add: {}; subtract: {}; calendar: {}; clone: {}; valueOf: {}; local: {}; isLocal: {}; utc: {}; isUTC: {}; isUtc: {}; parseZone: {}; isValid: {}; invalidAt: {}; hasAlignedHourOffset: {}; ... 71 more ...; propertyIsEn
umerable: {}; }' is not assignable to type 'Moment'.
          Types of property 'format' are incompatible.
            Type '{}' is not assignable to type '(format?: string | undefined) => string'.
              Type '{}' provides no match for the signature '(format?: string | undefined): string'.  TS2322

    56 |     const schema = reporterInformationSchema(t);
    57 |     const { control, formState: { errors }, handleSubmit, setValue, trigger } = useForm<ReporterInformationModel>({
  > 58 |         resolver: yupResolver(schema),
       |         ^
    59 |         defaultValues: {
    60 |             ...reporterInformation,
    61 |         },
```

This is the useForm code:

```
const { control, formState: { errors }, handleSubmit, setValue, trigger } = useForm<InfoModel>({
        resolver: yupResolver(schema),
        defaultValues: {
            ...reporterInformation,
        },
    });
```

where the InfoModel is:

```
    dateOfBirth?: moment.Moment | null;
    firstName: string | null;
    lastName: string | null;
```

I've narrowed the problem down to that the error is due to the dateOfBirth field, which is moment.

Answer (score 1):

this is a design limitation. We do not recommend to put complex object like moment in your form. Here is a similar issue: https://github.com/react-hook-form/resolvers/issues/258

Comment: Realized that. To accomplish the desired outcome, I had to use extend my interface using Omit and changing the dateOfBirth field to be Date, and changing it back to Moment when storing the data.